# Trouble removing quotes from dynamic sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to remove quotes from this dynamic sql so it would be just a script.

```
set @sqlDNB= '
 SELECT DISTINCT
                   Null CustomerID
                   ,EntityID MCVID
                   ,business_name CustomerName
                   ,physical_City +  ',' + physical_state +  '' + cast(physical_zip as varchar(7)) Address
                   ,'' RM
                   ,'' SubGroup
                   ,'' HierarchyType
                   ,'' status 
                   ,DNB.dunsnum DunsNumber
                   ,'DNB' Source
              from SOR.T_DunAndBradstreet DNB with (nolock)
              left outer join SOR.T_McvDuns MCVDUNS with (nolock)
              on DNB.dunsnum  = MCVDUNS.DunsNumber
                +
 case
 when @p_SearchMethod ='BeginsWith' and @p_CustomerName !='' then 'and business_name like ''' + @p_CustomerName + ''' '
 when @p_SearchMethod ='Contains' and @p_CustomerName !=''  then 'and Contains (business_name,''"' + @p_CustomerName + '"'')'
 when @p_SearchMethod ='Exact' and @p_CustomerName !=''  then  'and business_name =''' + @p_CustomerName + ''' ' 
 else
 ''
end 

+ ' where not exists 
(select dunsnumber from sor.T_Customer customer where customer.DUNSnumber = DNB.dunsnum '
+  
case
 when @p_SearchMethod ='BeginsWith' and @p_CustomerName !='' then 'and customer.Name like ''' + @p_CustomerName + ''' '
 when @p_SearchMethod ='Contains' and @p_CustomerName !=''  then 'and Contains (customer.Name,''"' + @p_CustomerName + '"'')'
 when @p_SearchMethod ='Exact' and @p_CustomerName !=''  then  'and customer.Name =''' + @p_CustomerName + ''' ' 
 else
 ''
end 

if @p_TIN_SSN !='' 
begin
set  @sqlDNB =  @sqlDNB + ' and customer.TINorSSN =''' + @p_TIN_SSN + ''' ' 
end
if  @p_CustomerID !='' 
begin
set  @sqlDNB =  @sqlDNB + ' and customer.[MCVID] =''' + cast(@p_CustomerID as varchar(20)) + '''  '  
end 
set  @sqlDNB =  @sqlDNB + ')'
```

Comment: What have you tried and what is your question?  Removing all quotes from this would break your code.

Comment: I don't understand ... why don't you just remove them.

Comment: I am trying to remove quotes from case statement but theres a statement there ('and business name like') if i remove all quotes it throws an error. how do i remove all quotes without breaking the logic?

Comment: (If you want to learn more on the subject of Dynamic SQL, read [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) by Erland Sommarskog. Very good explanation of the whole subject!)

Answer (score 1):

Removing any single quotes from the following code will cause an error:

```
'and business_name like ''' + @p_CustomerName + ''' '
```

When ever you see `''` inside of a string in SQL it is representing a single `'`.  For example

```
declare @test varchar(12)
set @test = 'don''t'
select @test
```

Will return `don't`.

Therefore, removing any single quotes from the code block you mentioned will make your `like` break.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Thanks Abe for your reply. so there's no way i can remove quotes and make this script as a non dynamic sql? Its taking long time to execute

Answer (score 1):

A handy way to 'debug' this kind of scripts in the SQL Server Management Studio is as follows:

```
DECLARE @sqlDNB nvarchar(max);

set @sqlDNB = <your script here>;

PRINT @sqlDNB;
```

If you run this, you'll get specific error messages that you can use to modify your script. And in the end, the printed string is the SQL script, and you can copy and test that as well.

Comment: Hi Josien, actually i need to get rid of the dynamic sql and make it as a sql script.

Comment: The printed result of the above would be the script you are looking for.